# Multi-lingual site without subfolders

Tags: localization, multi-environment, routing

Would it be possible to have a cleaner site setup without all those 'locale' subfolders in the webroot? Somehow it looks like there's something similar already done here (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/services/HttpRequestService.php#L99) if I'm not wrong, wouldn't it be nicer to also just remove the locale if one is detected?

Bonus question :) :
Where in the hell is the actual Entry Slug -> Template resolving done? I know there's a lot of stuff happening with filters, action and resource requests. The closest I could get is that here the template/render controller gets triggered (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/framework/web/CWebApplication.php#L274) which in the end resolves to the action render method in the TemplatesController (https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php#L50), already with the correct $template parameter set.

Could someone guide me in a direction here?

Comment: You linked us to the `init` function... what are we supposed to be looking at? Confused.

Comment: What's the problem with `/webroot/en/index.php` being responsible for `http://example.com/en`? And why should the folder (incl. `index.php`) be removed, if the locale is detected?

Comment: ah sorry, I meant to link to line 130 where they shift the _segments array to remove the 'admin' part of the url. I think something similar could be done with the locales.

And I don't want to remove the folder, I want to shift the _segments array to remove the locale-segment from the url and set the current craft locale. Like that there would be no need to just copy paste the index.php in several different folders.

Comment: I think it's not so much *multiple locale subfolders in the webroot* as it is multiple webroots.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but here is a way to have unlimited locales with only a single subfolder in your public root directory.

1. Put all of your locale subfolders into a single folder, called `locales` for example. So your directory structure would be:

   ```
   public/locales/de/
   public/locales/es/
   public/locales/fr/
   ```
2. Make sure you update the craft path in each locale's `index.php` file accordingly:

   ```
   $craftPath = '../../../craft';
   ```
3. Then you just need the following code in your root `.htaccess` file to redirect to the appropriate subfolder:

   ```
   # Redirect locales
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(de|es|fr)/ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.+) /locales/$1 [QSA,L]
   ```

Comment: Drats. This folder arrangement sounded great, but didn't work for me. I moved the language folders (en|th|zh) into a /locales/ directory, changed $craftPath in each index.php, modified the .htaccess file with this code (changed to reflect the relevant language codes) — but it didn't work. I just get a "The requested URL was not found on this server" error. As far as I know the rewrite engine is working fine. Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: can you post your code somewhere so i can review it?